# How do I query select all my mysql rows under the modification of a stored function with a reddit-based algorithm?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-functions, reddit

I've spent the whole day googling and deleting and inserting trying to implement this code. I've been trying to implement a reddit-like site using php and mysql. I have been following another question: [PHP MYSQL Query Algorithm Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360470/php-mysql-query-algorithm-help/8829555#8829555) and it works very well and ranks rows according to the algorithm coded in the previous question within myphpadmin when I query a stored function

```
SELECT
*,
reddit_rank(`time_added`, `up_votes`, `down_votes`) as rank
FROM
`table`
ORDER BY
rank;
```

, but when I paste the query into my php file:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
$q= "SELECT *,reddit_rank(`time` , `votes_up` , `votes_down`) FROM `wallposts` ORDER BY rank LIMIT 0 , 30";
$r = mysql_query($q);
if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
...?>
```

It doesn't work and I get a white HTML screen. So for example in my PHP when I have

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM wallposts ORDER BY votes_up DESC";
```

my reddit/facebook-like wall has prepended each of my rows from mysql and everything works just fine.  but when i change it to

```
$q= "SELECT *,reddit_rank(`time` , `votes_up` , `votes_down`) FROM `wallposts` ORDER BY rank LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

the webpage returns nothing but a white screen even though I know it works in myphpadmin.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is it not possible to query a select all with a stored function to order the results in php?

Comment: You'll need to better define "doesn't work". Are you getting an error? Is it producing different results than you expect?

Comment: Thanks Devon for pushing me to be clearer.  I mean there is no output.  So for example in my PHP when I have $q = "SELECT * FROM wallposts ORDER BY votes_up DESC"; everything works just fine.  but when i change it to $q= "SELECT *,reddit_rank(`time` , `votes_up` , `votes_down`) FROM `wallposts` ORDER BY rank LIMIT 0 , 30"; the webpage returns nothing but a white screen.

Comment: Try adding a `try ... catch` around the query and fetch to handle any exceptions and print the value of `mysql_num_rows($r)` to see if you're getting anything back.

Comment: It appears that there are no values in the table or more likely that the table is not being detected.  But there certainly is a table and values, I assure you.

Comment: In your original SQL you have `reddit_rank(...) as rank`, but in the php, the `as rank` is absent. I would expect there is an error from the `order by rank`, since there is no `rank` in the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution by creating a view and then querying that view instead of the original table.  After I queried the stored function in myphpadmin:

```
SELECT
*,
reddit_rank(`time_added`, `up_votes`, `down_votes`) as rank
FROM
`table`
ORDER BY
rank;
```

I then created a view after those results were returned.  Then instead of querying the same way in my PHP file, I queried the new mysql view with:

```
SELECT * FROM [view] ORDER BY rank
```

Voila!